# AWS Cloud Formation Launch Configuration files section

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template and everything works really well apart from creating a file on the EC2 instance as part of the LaunchConfiguration.

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" :
    {
      "files" :
      {
          "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf" :
          {
            "content" : "<VirtualHost *:80> </VirtualHost>",
            "mode"    : "000644",
            "owner"   : "root",
            "group"   : "root"
          }
      }
    }
```

I realise this file wont work but i wanted a simple example without extra Fn:: functions involved.

Basically this file doesn't get created. It doesn't exist on the EC2 instance AMI that is part of this Launch Configuration. I thought it should be created with the specified content from the template. I know this Launch Configuration is being used as the UserData script is being executed. But the files section isn't working.

Theres also no obvious messages in cloud-init.log or cloud-init-output.log.

Im looking for pointers on either how to debug this (can i execute part of my template from the command line and see more output ?) or ideas for why this file isn't being created.

Ive had a good hunt around the web and come up empty - the syntax is pretty simple and no errors so I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

I suppose I'm assuming that the cfg-init script will have the correct access rights to write a file in /etc.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about how `cfn-init` works and how you can feed the metadata to a cloudformation stack.

Looking at your code, it seems that you are passing metadata to cloudformation. what you wrote is **feeding** the metadata to cloudformation.

Now you need to have this metadata **executed** on the instance with the help of `cfn-init` script.

Refer:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I don't think this is correct.  According to the documentation your links point to, the section of the cloudformation template in the question should create a file.  I also suspect permissions, but I'm having a similar problem and haven't solved it yet.